# Is there any way to schedule a function with parameters in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I want a function to take a name of database/schema as a input and check weather that database is active or not every 5 min and then log it in a different table.
Sort of like monitoring the database

I have a function say repeat

```
function repeat(String database_name) {
     //check database_name can be connected or not
}
```

How to pass value inside the function repeat (if not parameter) when I will annotate it with @scheduled

Comment: You will need to clarify what you mean by "I need to pass parameters". Scheduled functions are just that; scheduled to run at specified time period without any user interaction. If you need to pass a parameter for invocation then it is really not a scheduled task. What is the use-case for this?

Comment: How are you expecting to provide the parameters then?

Comment: From where have you taken these parameters in your initial solution? Are they from the database? Are they user input? Please clarify

Comment: yes the parameters are from database @Lino

Comment: @Rupeshjuyal then you can simply fetch these values in the scheduled method itself

Comment: I get your point and thats where I got confused because till now it was same data(say same row to pass) but now data is changing what can I do?

Comment: @Rupeshjuyal Check my answer. It should provide a solution but you should update your question with more information like what parameters types are needed, and if they're always the same or if they change dynamically.

Comment: @jason thnx I will try it and will sure change the question...Its my 1st question on stackoverflow will try to improve the question

Comment: @Rupeshjuyal No problem, we all have to start somewhere. If it's not a valid solution let me know and i'll see if I can provide a more suitable answer upon the question being updated.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this would be to instead create an object that represents the parameters and on that execution after 5 minutes, obtain that object and use the internal state as a representation of the parameters. You have to ensure that MyEventService contains a reference to Event before the execution every 5 minutes. Without more input on the original post it's impossible to know how/when you're doing this.

If the parameters never change then I suggest making the service immutable, and removing the event class, and just providing the values via properties using @Value.

```java
class Event {

    private final String myString;

    // constructor, getter

}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyEventService {

    private Event event;

    // constructor, setter, getter

}
```

```java
class MyScheduledTask {

    @Autowired
    private MyEventService eventService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300_000)
    public void execute() {
        Event event = eventService.getEvent();

        if (event == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No event to process.");
        }
        // process event
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope it provides a solution for you.

Answer (score -2):

Actually `@Scheduled` takes parameters. Use the parameter `fixedRate` for specify the interval in milliseconds:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000‬)
public void youFunction() {
}
```

will execute it every 5 minutes.

If you need to specify in interval during runtime via the method parameter see my answer here:
[Is it possible to call a spring scheduled method manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151816/is-it-possible-to-call-a-spring-scheduled-method-manually/53048994#53048994)

You can use a `TaskScheduler` and manually schedule tasks via

```
taskScheduler.schedule(task1, new PeriodicTrigger(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
```

where the `5` could also be a parameter.

Comment: I think OP meant to pass *method* parameters

Comment: And technically, annotation "parameters" are called [*elements*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html)